# Get Facebook UserID

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Using Facebook's new Open Graph technologies launched just recently at their F8 Conference, how do I retrieve the facebook user id when a facebook user hits my open graph object?  Is this even possible at all?

As per this video:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/564/

I've created [the object](http://share.pazooza.com/share/97e98521-e56b-4fdb-b2d8-f562b0409ef6.htm)

I've also initialized the object and action on facebook:

```
object --> video

action --> recommend
```

If you go to the above .htm file and go view source, you will see the meta tags that I am using.  I am referring to my `pazooza:video` object type, the one I created on facebook.

But the point of this is that when a facebook user hits the .htm page to view the video, then I want to record that users hit in the database.

Does fb send a signed_request or user id via the querystring or do I subscribe to the .htm file somehow and my server gets a response from facebook?  I'm a lil confused any help would be appreciated.

I'm using ASP.Net MVC (Facebook C# SDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found the answer, well part of it.

My architectural approach to the problem was wrong.  I've spoken to one of the developers on the facebook c# sdk and some of the samples he gave made me realise how the open graph works.  Or "facebooks" version of it anyway.

The MVC design pattern reigns supreme in this case.  By having actions mimic the actions in your facebook open graph implementation you can now publish real-time events into the graph and have them available to new and existing users.

See this post: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/274238